# laravel 5.2 relationship not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 website and I am having trouble getting my relationship data to show. It was working fine before but I can't see my data. I am not getting any errors.

View

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>HAWB</th>
        <th>Pallet Count</th>
        <th>Piece Count</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($cfs->hawbs as $hawb)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$hawb->hawb}}">
                    {{$hawb->hawb}}
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{$cfs->hawb->pallet_ct}}</td>
            <td>{{$hawb->piece_ct}}</td>
            <td>{{$hawb->weight_no}} {{$hawb->weight_type}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <div id="{{$hawb->hawb}}" class="collapse">
                Insert more info here
            </div>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
public function getCfsStep(Request $request, $step)
{
    $cfs = DB::table('cfs_deliveries');

    $account = Account::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

    return view('cfs.step_' . $step, compact('account', 'cfsDelivery'), ['cfs' => $request->session()->get('cfs')]);
}
```

CFSDelivery Model

```
public function hawbs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Hawb', 'cfs_delivery_id');
}
```

Hawb Model

```
public function cfsDelivery()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CfsDelivery');
}
```

**Edit**

I'm now getting this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$hawbs (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dsd-cms/resources/view‌​s/cfs/step_3.blade.p‌​hp

Comment: Is anything showing?

Comment: None of the data. Just the other page elements (layout elements, a button and an image). But no table or data.

Comment: In your controller, there's a variable `$cfs`; but in the `compact` function you are passing `'cfsDelivery'`.

Comment: Now getting this error

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$hawbs (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dsd-cms/resources/views/cfs/step_3.blade.php

Comment: So I changed the variable name from $cfs to $cfsDelivery. I had forgotten to change it back when I was trying different things out. No data is being passed to the view for $cfsDelivery. I am thinking it has to do with how my redirect is set up. Does anyone know how to modify this so that i can have data for multiple variables passed and stored into the session ($cfs)?

Comment: Correction: $cfsDelivery is being passed through but the relationship between $cfsDelivery and hawbs() is not being recognized.